# How to get left out table width in a table in itext

Tags: java, itext

I am new to iText. I want to generate a pdf with one table. Table consist of 3 cell (cell1 ,cell2, cell3).

Cell1 and cell2 data is dynamic text. After cell1 and cell2 are filled up, I want to fit some text in cell3 for left out space i.e. remaining space in that table. But I am not able to know the remaining space for cell3, as cell1 and 2 are dynamic.
I added fixed height.So text is truncating automatically.**I want to append '...' in cell3  if the text is truncated?**
[image: sample image]

```
private static void addData(Document document) throws Exception {

    PdfPTable targetCompanyDetails = new PdfPTable(1);
    targetCompanyDetails.setWidthPercentage(100);
    targetCompanyDetails.setWidths(new float[] { 100 });

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(
            new Paragraph("", PdfUtil.getFont(FontNames.AVENIRLTCOM_MEDIUM.getFontName(), 12, 1, BaseColor.WHITE)));
    cell.setBorder(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

    PdfPTable targetCompanyInfo = new PdfPTable(3);
    targetCompanyInfo.setWidthPercentage(100.5f);
    targetCompanyInfo.setWidths(new float[] { 69, 83, 63 });

    PdfPCell firstCell = new PdfPCell();
    //firstCell.setBorderWidth(0);
    firstCell.setFixedHeight(130f);
    Font companyNameFont = PdfUtil.getFont(FontNames.AVENIRLTCOM_85HEAVY.getFontName(), 10F, Font.NORMAL,
            new BaseColor(Color.decode(ColorCodes._336699.getColorCode()).getRGB()));
    Chunk ck = new Chunk("oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle oracle orac oracle oracle oracle orac", companyNameFont);
    Paragraph targetParagraph = new Paragraph();
    targetParagraph.setLeading(11.25f);
    targetParagraph.add(ck);
    PdfPCell targetCompanyName = new PdfPCell();
    targetCompanyName.addElement(targetParagraph);
    PdfPTable targetCompanyDescTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    targetCompanyDescTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    targetCompanyDescTable.setWidths(new float[] { 100 });
    targetCompanyDescTable.addCell(targetCompanyName);

    firstCell.addElement(targetCompanyDescTable);

    Font sectorFont = PdfUtil.getFont(FontNames.AVENIRLTCOM_85HEAVY.getFontName(), 10F, Font.NORMAL,
            new BaseColor(Color.decode(ColorCodes._336699.getColorCode()).getRGB()));
    Chunk ck1 = new Chunk("oracle Akk soft ", sectorFont);
    Paragraph sectorParagraph = new Paragraph();
    sectorParagraph.setLeading(11.25f);
    sectorParagraph.add(ck1);
    PdfPCell sectorName = new PdfPCell();
    sectorName.addElement(sectorParagraph);
    PdfPTable sectorTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    sectorTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    sectorTable.setWidths(new float[] { 100 });
    sectorTable.addCell(sectorName);
    firstCell.addElement(sectorTable);




    Font descFont = PdfUtil.getFont(FontNames.AVENIRLTCOM_85HEAVY.getFontName(), 10F, Font.NORMAL,
            new BaseColor(Color.decode(ColorCodes._336699.getColorCode()).getRGB()));
    String content = "As there are 11 entries in the collection this means that the for the final row of the table you only add one cell. Thus, that row is incomplete and won't be drawn.You should either track whether the number of entries you added is even (e.g. by counting or by switching a boolean value); if it is not even, you should finally add another, empty cell.(Or if you want to rely on iText not drawing incomplete rows, simply always add an empty cell after the loop.)";
    Chunk ck2 = new Chunk(content, descFont);
    Paragraph descParagraph = new Paragraph();
    descParagraph.setLeading(11.25f);
    descParagraph.add(ck2);
    PdfPCell descName = new PdfPCell();
    descName.addElement(descParagraph);
    PdfPTable descTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    descTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    descTable.setWidths(new float[] { 100 });
    descTable.addCell(descName);
    firstCell.addElement(descTable);


    PdfPCell secondCell = new PdfPCell();
    //secondCell.setBorderWidth(0);
    secondCell.setFixedHeight(130f);

    PdfPCell thiredCell = new PdfPCell();
    //thiredCell.setBorderWidth(0);
    thiredCell.setFixedHeight(130f);


    targetCompanyInfo.addCell(firstCell);
    targetCompanyInfo.addCell(secondCell);
    targetCompanyInfo.addCell(thiredCell);
    cell.addElement(targetCompanyInfo);
    targetCompanyDetails.addCell(cell);
    document.add(targetCompanyDetails);

    float totalWidth = targetCompanyDescTable.getTotalWidth();
    System.out.println("totalWidth : " + totalWidth);
    System.out.println("totalWidth : " + targetCompanyDetails.getTotalWidth());
    System.out.println("totalWidth : " + targetCompanyInfo.getTotalWidth());
}
```

Comment: Hi rockey, welcome to stackoverflow. Please tell us exactly how you are stuck and possibly show us that you have put in your effort before you asked the question.

Comment: Can any one help?